# h:dataTable always displays one row; won't display zero rows

Tags: css, jsf, jsf-2

I'm working in a legacy JSF web app, and my h:dataTable element is giving me trouble. Normally, it displays exactly how I want it - a header and several rows, all with proper padding and margins and everything.

[image: h:datatable displaying three rows correctly]

However, if I try to display a table with zero rows (which is a valid use case for me), JSF still renders one row, albeit empty of contents.

[image: h:dataTable rendering one empty row when it should be rendering zero rows]

Here's the source code for this h:dataTable:

```
<h:dataTable styleClass="table" value="#{backingBean.emptyList}" var="result">

    <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">First Column</f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{result}"/>
    </h:column>

    <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">Second Column</f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{result}"/>
    </h:column>

    <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">Third Column</f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{result}"/>
    </h:column>

</h:dataTable>
```

Here's what's being rendered by the browser:

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">First Column</th>
            <th scope="col">Second Column</th>
            <th scope="col">Third Column</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Here are the methods in the backing bean that give me my result list:

```
public List<String> getEmptyList() { // incorrectly renders 1 empty row
    return Collections.emptyList();
}

public List<String> getThreeRows() { // correctly renders 3 rows
    return Arrays.asList(new String[] {"row1", "row2", "row3"});
}
```

Why is JSF rendering this empty row? I would have expected the `<tbody>` to just be empty. Is this the correct behavior for JSF? or do I have something misconfigured?

Please advise,

-August

Comment: Because your resultset contains one entry that is empty??? [mcve] please

Comment: I've updated the question to be more concise.

Comment: Seemes reproducible: Even a trivial dataTable `<h:dataTable><h:column/></h:dataTable>` has a body with a row with a cell: `<table>
<tbody>
<tr><td></td></tr></tbody>
</table>`

Comment: Is this just how JSF2 works? I'm surprised that it's rendering the <tr> at all. Maybe that was a conscious design decision? Or maybe it's a bug?

Comment: I cannot imagine this being a bug unless you are using the latest greatest snapshot and it is an omission.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per the source code of Mojarra 2.3.8 this is encouraged behavior, the `TableRenderer` (as its' name says) is responsible for and [explicitly doing this](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/mojarra/blob/2d22f78f81548c10f2c48a8fd8a04caa1628c0b3/impl/src/main/java/com/sun/faces/renderkit/html_basic/TableRenderer.java#L145):

`com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.TableRenderer.encodeChildren(FacesContext, UIComponent)`:

```
if(!renderedRow) {
        // if no row with data has been rendered, render that empty row in question:
        this.renderEmptyTableRow(writer, data);
}
```

Your options include:

1) Add a rendered attribute to your dataTable:

```
<h:dataTable value="#{backingBean.entityList}"
  rendered="#{not empty backingBean.entityList}" ...>
  ...
</h:dataTable>
<h:outputText rendered="#{empty backingBean.entityList}"
  value="No data to display, sooo sorry :-("/>
```

2) Override the `TableRenderer` to do the job better fitting your needs:

```
package my;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.faces.component.UIComponent;
import javax.faces.component.UIData;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;

import com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.TableRenderer;

public class CustomTableRenderer extends TableRenderer {
    @Override
    public void encodeChildren(final FacesContext context, final UIComponent component) throws IOException {
        final UIData data = (UIData) component;
        final int rowCount = data.getRowCount();
        if (rowCount > 0) {
            super.encodeChildren(context, component);
        } else {
            // do what super.encodeChildren does, but your way ...
        }
    }
}
```

Sadly you can not just override `com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.TableRenderer.renderEmptyTableRow(ResponseWriter, UIComponent)` and make it do nothing because it is `private`.

In `faces-config.xml` register your custom renderer:

```
<render-kit>
    <renderer>
        <component-family>javax.faces.Data</component-family>
        <renderer-type>javax.faces.Table</renderer-type>
        <renderer-class>my.CustomTableRenderer</renderer-class>
    </renderer>
</render-kit>
```

Edit: The behavior in question was introduced [in a commit](https://github.com/javaserverfaces/mojarra/commit/c778782e365d32383205d56ae849848127c3e81d) fixing an [issue #1009 with comment](https://github.com/javaserverfaces/mojarra/issues/1013):

```
Fix for issue 1009: Rendered h:dataTable/h:panelGrid without rows/content do not validate against XHTML 1.0 Transitional (and html4)

git-svn-id: https://svn.java.net/svn/mojarra~svn/trunk@7669 761efcf2-d34d-6b61-9145-99dcacc3edf1
```

Too bad I could not find that issue anymore, [but @Kukeltje did!](https://github.com/javaserverfaces/mojarra/issues/1013)

Comment: Hey thanks! As long as Sun has purposefully decided to render an empty row, I think I won't change it. I was just afraid I had messed up my xhtml. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @AugustZellmer You're welcome. I just edited the answer adding a link to the commit confirming this is intentional behaviour.

Comment: And see why JSF version info is always relevant to post!

Comment: Issues are now in github and if you add 4 to the original issue number from the old java.net site you get the issue again: https://github.com/javaserverfaces/mojarra/issues/1013

Comment: @Kukeltje nice1 didn't know that - thanx :-)

Comment: I believe even they are now in a different repo. Check the references at the end of this issue

Comment: @Kukeltje Yes mojarra work now goes on in [/eclipse-ee4j/mojarra](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/mojarra). Am excited on what's coming with all that jakarta migration. Do they rename all packages? (javax.faces, com.sun, ...) Have ben reading [a blog entry by Arjam Tijms shortly](https://blog.payara.fish/jakarta-ee-9-2019-outlook).